# Switching between search engines in Firefox search box quickly?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has this search box next to URL box, and to just use default search engine, it's just Cmd-K query Enter. If I want to query something else just this once - let's say flickr, it's far too much effort:

- Switch to mouse
- Open dropdown menu with search engine
- Select new engine
- Switch to keyboard
- Type query
- Switch to mouse again
- Open dropdown
- Select default engine back

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps with some prefixes for each engine so I'd just type `flickr cats` and it would search `cats` on flickr? (no prefix => default engine)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd> switches to next/previous search engine in the list.

If you want the search box to always go back to the default after a non-default search, install and customize the [SearchLoad Options](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3544/) extension.

Alternatively, you may be looking for [Second Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4096/).

If you really want to be able to use a specific engine by typing its name, you want something like [Obnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8823/) or even Firefox's [built-in keyword search](http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/search+bar#Keywords) feature. There are many other extensions for variations on keyword searching. Browse the Firefox [Add-ons website](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/).

Answer (score 1):

With the modern search setup, <kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd> switches to next/previous search engine in the displayed list of alternatives.

[image: search engines list]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd> switches the default engine.

[image: default search engine]