# Change Firefox search engine from the keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching between search engines in Firefox search box quickly?](https://superuser.com/questions/168083/switching-between-search-engines-in-firefox-search-box-quickly)

I know that if I hit ctrl + K the cursor jumps to the search box.  However, I have a number of search engines I use fairly frequently, and the one I want is never the one that's selected.

Is it possible, without switching to the mouse, to rotate between the various search engines I have installed?  (It's Firefox 3 on Windows, if that's relevant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the search field, then you're able to switch by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>.

You can even type the first letter of the search engine you want and it is automatically selected. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> and then <kbd>W</kbd> results in Wikipedia being selected.

Comment: I have just confirmed that this also works on Windows.

Comment: This still works except for the typing the letter of the search engine part—now, the "W" would just appear in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answer provided by slhck, you could also use an extension. I personally prefer the [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/) addon to Firefox. It gives vim like key bindings to a large portion of Firefox's interface so that I hardly ever have to reach for the mouse for web navigation.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative technique, have you considered searching using [Smart Keywords](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Smart%20keywords)? For example, you can search for socks on Google by just going to the address bar (Alt+D) and then typing `g socks`. To search Bing instead of Google, do the same and type `b socks`. You can easily set up Smart Keywords for almost any search engine or website with a search service.